# Using InStr/InStrB to find Chr(13)

Tags: string, vba, vbscript, asp-classic

Recently I've come across a line that looks like :

```
Private Function FindCR(BinaryString)
  FindCR = InstrB(1, BinaryString, Chr(13))
End Function
```

Basically, I feed it a binary string, and it's supposed to give me the index of carriage returns. For this example, let's use `ChrB(65) & ChrB(13) & ChrB(66) & ChrB(13) & ChrB(67) & ChrB(0)`, which is equivalent to :

> A
>
> B
>
> C

However, in this case `FindCR` would return me 0 since `Chr(13)` = `\13\0` and my string looks like `\65\13\66\13\67\0`.

I've tried to get around it by replacing the `Chr(13)` with `ChrB(13)` (binary representation of CR, instead of Char Representation, so `\13` instead of `\13\0`), but instrB returns `Arg1` (1 in this case) when Arg3 is of length 0 (and while `lenB(ChrB(13))`is 1, `len(ChrB(13))`is 0.

Is there any ways of finding the first carriage return in a binary string without having to manipulate the string and/or working with the chars in the form of `\xx`?

Comment: Contrary to what you think, `ChrB(65) & ChrB(13) & ChrB(66) & ChrB(13) & ChrB(67) & ChrB(0)` is not `A\nB\nC\0`. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: @Tomalak I'm trying to fix a module that worked up until recently, who's looking for `Chr(13)` in a file that contains line feeds as `ChrB(13)`, basically. So I need to find the binary index of `ChrB(13)`in a given binary string. Otherwise, apart from `\n` not being necessarily the same as `\13`, what would be the difference between `A \n B \n C \0` and `A \13 B \13 C \0`?

Comment: "A file that contains line feeds" - So... if it's a text file, why don't you read it as a text file and use normal string functions on it? (You mean `ChrB(65) & ChrB(0) & ChrB(13) & ChrB(0) & ChrB(66) & ChrB(0) & ChrB(13) & ChrB(0) & ChrB(67) & ChrB(0) & ChrB(0)& ChrB(0)` as the input, but that really looks dangerous to me, as if you are trying to solve the wrong problem with the wrong tools. Hence my question.)

Comment: There is really no use for a solitary `Chr(13)` in any properly formed data; TXT or otherwise. If you are looking for a **linefeed** then you should be looking for `Chr(10)` (aka *vbLF*). If you are looking for **carriage returns** then look for `Chr(13)&Chr(10)` (aka *vbCRLF*). A `Chr(13)` should not be without an accompanying `Chr(10)`. A linefeed equate a `<br/>` in HTML while a carriage return is more like a `<p>`.

Comment: Neither `Chr(13)` nor `ChrB(13)` represents _Line feed_ (vbLF) but _Carriage return_ (vbCR).

Comment: @Jeeped that is not entirely true, it depends on the source of the file. If it Windows OS it's likely to be `vbCrLf`, for most others like UNIX based systems it's `vbCr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with binary strings, you may be limiting yourself by only checking for carriage returns. In my experience, someone can use a different text editor for a slightly different string and/or your source data may change (even from test to production). End of line sequences can be vbCR or vbCR+vbLF or even other combinations. I suggest rolling your own to get the flexibility you may need:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function FindByteCode(binString() As Byte, _
                              Optional findChar As String = vbCr, _
                              Optional startChar As Long = 0) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim start As Long
    Dim eos As Long
    If startChar > 0 Then
        start = startChar
    Else
        start = LBound(binString)
    End If
    eos = 0
    For i = start To UBound(binString)
        If binString(i) = AscB(findChar) Then
            eos = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    FindByteCode = eos
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim testStr As String
    testStr = "where is the end of the first vbCR " & Chr(13) & _
              " and then the second?" & vbCr & vbLf
    Debug.Print "first  vbCR at " & FindByteCode(StrConv(testStr, vbFromUnicode))
    Debug.Print "second vbCR at " & FindByteCode(StrConv(testStr, vbFromUnicode), startChar:=36)
    Debug.Print "first  vbLF at " & FindByteCode(StrConv(testStr, vbFromUnicode), findChar:=vbLf)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what's up with binary strings, as in what's the use case? I am at a loss.

Comment: OP tagged the question for both VBA and VBScript, so I believed my answer was still relevant and applicable. As I understand it, the key difference impacting the example code above would be declaring the variables without a specific type (VBScript only supporting variables of `Variant` type). At least, the example illustrates my point in avoiding the limitations of the OP's original approach.

Comment: In VBA at least, the `String` type is represented in memory as Unicode two-byte characters, whereas a binary string (`Byte Array` in VBA parlance) is represented by single byte characters (ASCII in this case). The example code above should work for a `String` just as well (if the first arg is changed to`String` I think the returned position value is actually the same number given the input string). The use case is generally reading from an existing text file (less likely in VBScript), an HTML form field, or HTTP POST input string not in Unicode format.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I accepted it because it helped me find the issue and was the only answer. However, since the issue ended up being only tangential to the question, I couldn't really provide my own answer and accept it.